# ListView recycle issue

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview

I have a listview with custom adapter, there is an imageview in each row and I download images to set from remote server by URL passing it to AsyncTask. My code is working but when I scroll the listview, downloaded images of ImageViews are downloaded again.

I want to download images for first creation of listview. I have researched many topics but I didn't understand anything. What should I do?

My custom adapter is below ...

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, ProgramInfo values) {

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      }

       @Override
       public int getCount(){

           return values.getSize();
            }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            TextView programName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.programName);
            TextView programTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.programTime);
            TextView programState = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.programState);
            ImageView programImage = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.programImage);


            programName.setText(values.programNames.get(position));
            programTime.setText(values.programTimes.get(position));


            new DownloadImage(programImage).execute(values.programImageUrls.get(position)); // download images


        return rowView;

    }
```

And my AsyncTask ...

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     ImageView bmImage;

     public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
         this.bmImage = bmImage;
     }

     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         String urldisplay = urls[0];
         Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
         try {
             HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(urldisplay).openConnection();
             urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
             InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
             mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
             urlConnection.disconnect();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return mIcon11;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        } 
     }
```

Thanks...

Comment: use universal image loader lib for imageview in listview

Comment: take a look at the view holder pattern in order to optimise recycling. Also you can make use of a Bitmap cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in adapters every thing in side **getView** will be executed for each new row appeared 
so you must use **ViewHolder** inside **getView**to save state of elements for each row
and us if statement check if ImageView is null before reDownload it....
And this is amazing example of what I speak about...

[Asynchronous Image Loader In Android ListView](http://javatechig.com/android/asynchronous-image-loader-in-android-listview)